# Filtering Atlas coverage layer by current feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm working with an atlas in QGIS and have a coverage layer with over 2000 features. Due to the large number of features, it takes a considerable amount of time to load. I'd like to optimize this by limiting the atlas to display only the current feature or a range around the current feature (e.g., `$currentfeature +/- 5`).

I've attempted to use the "Filter with" option in the Atlas settings with expressions like `"id" = @atlas_featureid` and `"id" = $id`, but neither seems to achieve the desired result.

How can I effectively filter the coverage layer to display only the current feature or a specific range around it?

[EDIT]

My coverage layer consists of the colored polygons shown in the image below. To set up the Atlas, I can right-click on these polygons and select the desired Atlas, as demonstrated in the image:

[image: selection of features to create atlas]

The result is this atlas:

[image]

When I don't use a "filter", it cycles through the entire size of the coverage layer (which has over 2000 polygons), making the creation process quite slow. I can implement a static filter like `"id" in (10,12,13)` and the atlas cycle through polygons 10,12,13 only. I'm curious if there's a way to implement a dynamic filter that limits the number of features in the coverage layer to cycle through, perhaps using something like `"id" = @atlas_featureid`:

[image]

But it seems not taking into account project variables for atlas filtering

Comment: Thanks for adding in the images. So when you say "when I don't use a 'filter', it cycles through the entire size of the coverage layer" - is this when you are trying to export as a pdf/jpg/svg, QGIS tries to export all 2000+ atlas pages and not the one that you've just indicated? You would like to know how to export only that specific page that you've set the atlas feature for?

Comment: Not necessarily, for export. In the dropdown menu close to the export to pdf icon, it shows the entire coverage dataset (>2000 entries). I would like to reduce the size of the features (polygons) for which it creates the atlas.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for the clarification. That makes it much clearer - I think you are right that using atlas variables for the filter is kind of self-referencing so it won't work. I have a somewhat kludgy alternative that I'll post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten answer to respond to updated question.

This does require a few more clicks but try using `is_selected()` in the Atlas Filter and use the Select tool to select which features you want the Atlas to cycle through.

When selecting a new feature you will need to switch the atlas on and off. See below screengrab:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the exhaustive answer @she_weeds. However, I really want to limit the features the atlas cycle through, based on the one that is identified in the main project (using right click and select "Set as Atlas feature").

Comment: Could you update your question maybe with some screenshots to show exactly what you mean? I'm afraid I don't understand your question - do you mean you have an atlas layer (e.g., countries) and you want to limit the visible features from *other* layers (e.g. cities) that are outside the active feature? (e.g. only show cities inside the active country?)

Comment: I've added some images for clarification.

Comment: Answer rewritten to respond to question

Comment: Thanks @she_weeds. This is the closest solution to my problem to date.